# Place one div on the left side and two divs on the right with display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I thought that `height: max-content` might do the trick but it didn't.
I don't want to fix this by adding another div. Is there a way to do this by using parent and only 3 child elements?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 54%;
  background: #000;
  margin: 1px;
  height: max-content;
}

.item.itm1 {
  flex-basis: 44%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item itm1">1</div>
  <div class="item itm2">2</div>
  <div class="item itm3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it have to be `display: flex` or could you use `display: grid`? Flex isn't really meant for doing that unless you use multiple flex box containers.

Comment: I think you should just make them in two parts,first "div" in the first part and the rest in the second part, just like that

Comment: @StevenLambert not necessarily but I needed expert's opinion as I wasn't sure that it is impossible in flex.

Comment: @A.El-zahaby It does works but I am willing to achieve it with fewer divs...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion I don think it is possible with help of "flex" you can achieve what you want.if you okay to use one more "div", it is possible, here is the code snippet for that.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item itm1">1</div>
    <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column;width:55%">
        <div class="item itm2">2</div>
        <div class="item itm3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing but I am trying to achieve this without adding parent div to the 2 items

Comment: Hi Ali, I built it without using extra div. here is my JSFiddle, hope this is what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/w8bj5ck0/